# How to sort similar Keys in php Redis

Tags: php, redis

I get similar keys by using this code in php.

```
$cache = new Redis();
$cache->connect($this->host, $this->port);  
$allKeys = $cache->keys($key);
```

This is my output

```
Array
(
    [0] => detail_2
    [1] => detail_1
    [2] => detail_5
    [3] => detail_6
)
```

Here how to sort those keys, I'm using the SET method for key storage.

I tried this method for sorting `$cache->sort($key)` but it didn't help me.

Comment: Does the Redis library you're using have the feature to retrieve keys in a specific order? If not, how about `sort($allKeys)`?

Comment: sort($allKeys) -- it reurns 1 only

Comment: Can you show the actual code where you've tried using `sort($allKeys)`

Comment: function getSimilarKeys($key){
  $cache = new Redis();
  $cache->connect($this->host, $this->port); 
  $allKeys = $cache->keys($key); 
  echo "<pre>";print_r(sort($allKeys));exit;
  return $allKeys;
 }

Comment: From https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php : `Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.`

Comment: @Nima -- the output of redis returns   ( [0] => getvbnewsdetail_2381    [1] => getvbnewsdetail_4280    [2] => getvbnewsdetail_697    [3] => getvbnewsdetail_3094 ). I need to sort like (  [0] => getvbnewsdetail_4280   [1] => getvbnewsdetail_3094    [2] => getvbnewsdetail_2381    [3] => getvbnewsdetail_697 ). so we can get the latest first. can you please tell me how to do this?

Comment: You really should consider referring to PHP manual more often. `sort` function accepts its argument by reference, it sorts the array itself. It does not return a sorted array like you expected. Try this: `sort($allKeys); print_r($allKeys);` to see how it works.